Getting level counts from 2 variable+ glm output
I need to get the counts of all levels in a model with 2 or more levels. Someone helped me get the counts for when there was only one variable in the model with "n" = table(output[[i]]$model[,2]), which worked great. I can call a second column with table(output[[i]]$model[,3]). But I can't use both in my current loop without getting an error.
# Code to set up sample dataset and loading libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
install.packages("AER")
library("AER")
data(Affairs, package="AER")
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs >  0] <- 1
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs == 0] <- 0

Affairs <- Affairs %>% 
  mutate_at(c("affairs", "religiousness", "occupation", "rating", "ynaffair"), as.factor)

Affairs$religiousness <- relevel(Affairs$religiousness, ref="1")
Affairs$rating <- relevel(Affairs$rating, ref="1")
Affairs$gender <- relevel(Affairs$gender, ref="female")


## Setting up the loop

# Defining the data set, conditions, and control name
base_df <- as_tibble(Affairs) 
control_name <- "1"

# Categories to loop over - everything except control
exp_conditions <- unique(base_df$religiousness)
exp_conditions <- exp_conditions[exp_conditions != control_name]


# Here is an example model to show how the model data is called and summarized

sample_model <- glm(ynaffair ~ gender + occupation, family = binomial,  data = Affairs)

# Getting gender count
table(sample_model$model[,2])

# Getting occupation count
table(sample_model$model[,3])


# The loop
for(i in exp_conditions){
  condition <- base_df |>

    # only keep relevant conditions we're looping over
    dplyr::filter(religiousness %in% c(i, control_name))
  
  output[[i]] <- glm(ynaffair ~ gender + occupation, family = binomial,  data = condition)

  output_df_list[[i]] <- data.frame("Covariate"=names(output[[i]]$coefficients),
                                    "n"= table(output[[i]]$model[,2]), #Only gives count for sex on repeat
                                    #"n2"= table(output[[i]]$model[,3]), #Doesn't work
                                    "Beta_Estimate"=output[[i]]$coefficients,
                                    "P_val"=summary(output[[i]])$coefficients[,4],
                                    "CI_95_LL"=confint(output[[i]])[,1],
                                    "CI_95_UL"=confint.default(output[[i]])[,2]
                                    )
    rownames(output_df_list[[i]]) <- NULL             
}

output_df_sex <- do.call("rbind", output_df_list)
output_df_sex 


What I need:

I can try to pull the numbers individually, combine them, and then bind them to the rest of the data frame, but I am hoping there is a simpler way I am not thinking of.

As requested previously, please include your table of desired outputs in text format, not as an image/screenshot ...

Also, it's not immediately obvious how this question is different from your previous question ... ?

This code uses a loop instead of a function.

Your code seems to work error-free. What is the problem?
